# How to define multiple stylesheets in the Drupal 7 .info file

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I would like to define multiple stylesheets in the Drupal 7 .info file. This is what I am doing:

```
stylesheets[all][] = support/default.css
stylesheets[all][] = support/article.css
stylesheets[all][] = support/tinydropdown.css
scripts[] = support/tinydropdown.js
```

The only thing that loads in this setting is the first stylesheet. The other two stylesheets and the javascript don't load. I have tried clearing the cache and reloading the theme, but it does not work for me.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Just came across this.

Try adding 0, 1, 2 etc

```
stylesheets[all][0] = support/default.css
stylesheets[all][1] = support/article.css
stylesheets[all][2] = support/tinydropdown.css
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this.  See this document:
https://drupal.org/node/171209

Note the note, too.

> The .info file is cached. Adding or removing any styles will not be detected until the cache is cleared and the revised .info is read. (Do not confuse this with the theme registry.) You must clear the cache to see the changes.